# Why does daylight-saving have such a big impact on us and weekends don't?

Tags: sleep, human-factors

Last weekend, at least in Germany, the clock got switched from 2:00 AM to 3:00 AM.

Today I found a few articles, that suggest, that the daylight-saving has a big impact on people. [Judges punish harder](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0956797616678437?journalCode=pssa&) and [myocardial infarction rises](https://www.europeanreview.org/article/14306) after daylight saving. I've found those articles in [here](http://www.zeit.de/wissen/gesundheit/2018-03/schlafforschung-sommerzeit-zeitumstellung-uhrzeit-muedigkeit-schlaf/seite-2), which is a trustworthy German newspaper.

How is it, that just one hour of delay, has such a big impact on us? Me and most people I know, heavily change their sleeping habits on the weekends anyway. As for me, I stay up 2-4 hours later than usual, which is why I can't believe, that 1 hour makes such a difference.

Most people can sleep long on weekends anyways, so there shouldn't even be one hour of sleep missing.

Are those articles maybe drawing the wrong conclusions and connecting two things that might be correlated, but not linked?

[This](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/17017/what-is-the-effect-of-daylight-saving-time-on-attentiveness-and-productivity) SE question is related, but rather holds the information that I already got from the linked newspaper article.

Sidenote: Since sleep mainly happens in our brain I posted this in psychology & neuroscience, I hope this is correct. If it rather belongs in Biology please let me know. I also couldn't find any more tags than "sleep". If you can think of more feel free to tell me.